# For Each Loops and Multiple Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that is color coded.  I want to cycle through each row, and return a string denomenating which columns in that row are colored.  My approach was to define a vertical range of cells to cycle through, and then for each cell in that range define a horizontal range to cycle through.  The error I get says that the For variable is already in use.  This is the code I'm using:

```
Public Sub Months()

Dim Tally As String
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim Col As String

Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set R1 = Range(Selection.Address)

For Each cell In R1
    cell.Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlRight)).Select
    Set R2 = Range(Selection.Address)
    For Each cell In R2
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
            Col = Split(ActiveCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
            If Tally Is Nothing Then
                Set Tally = Col
            Else
                Set Tally = Tally + ";" + Col
            End If
            Range("DF" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = Tally
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks very much.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I do notice you haven't declared `cell` at the top. Perhaps add `Dim cell as Cell` for general clarity?

Comment: try changing 'For Each cell In R2' to 'For Each cell2 In R2'

Comment: @sous2817 that will superficially "fix" it, but it doesn't answer the question of `why`.  Also, this is a bad way of doing things, to use undeclared variables. There are also other errors further down in this code.

Comment: @PowerUser no that won't fix it, because the `cell` loop is already in use, it cannot be re-used. OP requires another variable for the second loop, and also would be a good idea to properly dimension them, per your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, `Option Explicit` will help you identify the cause of this error.

For starters, you don't need multiple ranges, only one range that defines the entire table. I will show you how to do that, below.

**As for the immediate question**:

In context, `For each cell in ... R1` where `cell` is not a special keyword, it's an implied variable that is being used.  When you later do `For each cell in R2`, Excel bawks at you because `cell` loop is already initiated, above.

i.e., it may be more obvious what the problem is, if we use something other than the pseudo keyword `cell`:

```
For i = 1 to 10
    For i = 3 to 44
        Msgbox i
    Next
Next
```

If the compiler could ever get to the message box line, what value of `i` would you expect it to display?  This is the cause of the error. Your iterator is already in use, you cannot re-use it.

Declare all of your variables, and use `Option Explicit` to avoid these mistakes in the future :)

**A better way to define a table's range**

However, it will be far more efficient to simply define ONE range, rather than haphazardly trying to define and redefine the row range for every row or column in the table.  Try something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Months()
Dim Tally As String
Dim tbl As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim Col As String

Set tbl = Range(Range("A2").End(xlDown), Range("A2").End(xlToRight))

For Each r In tbl.Rows
    For Each c In tbl.Columns
        Set cl = tbl.Cells(r, c)
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
            Col = Split(cl.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
'            If Tally Is Nothing Then
'                Set Tally = Col
'            Else
'                Set Tally = Tally + ";" + Col
'            End If
            Range("DF" & (cl.Row)).Select
            cl.Value = Tally
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

**Note:**

I have commented out the block of code pertaining to `Tally` variable as there are several errors:

- `Tally` is a string variable. Do not use the keyword `Set` to assign a string variable.
- `Tally` is a string variable, therefore `Is Nothing` will mismatch. Check for `Tally = vbNullString` or `Len(Tally) = 0` instead.
- While the operator `+` may allow string concatenation, I believe the preferred operator in VBA would be `&`, so although this may not cause an error, it's something you might change for disambiguation.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same variable name in a nested For loop:

```
For Each cell In R1
...
    For Each cell In R2
```

Change the "cell" variable in the second loop to something else.

Also, this line:

```
If Tally Is Nothing Then
```

will break.  Tally is defined as a String, not an object, so you should use "If Tally <> "" Then"

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid making selections if at all possible.

Untested:

```
Public Sub Months()

Dim Tally As String
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim Col As String
Dim c As Range, c2 As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set R1 = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    For Each c In R1.Cells
        Tally = ""
        Set R2 = ActiveSheet.Range(c, c.End(xlToRight)) 'not xlRight...
        For Each c2 In R2.Cells
            If c2.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
                Col = Split(c2.Address(), "$")(0)
                Tally = Tally & IIf(Len(Tally) > 0, ";", "") & Col 'Set not required...
            End If
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("DF" & c.Row).Value = Tally
    Next

End Sub
```